# SQL Server SPID and connection pooling

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

What is the max value for a SQL Server SPID? How long can a spid be dormant before connection pooling occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL can have about 65000 spids. The length of time that a connection is open has nothing to do with connection pooling. The driver that the client appliation uses controls if connection pooling is used.